# How to map normally with 2 class but use AfterMap in IEnumerable of the same 2 object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this classes

```
public class LegalDTO
{
    public int LegalId {get; set;}
    public string LegalName {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
    public Person Person2 {get; set;}
}

public class LegalModel
{
    public int LegalId {get; set;}
    public string LegalName {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I have this on my MappingProfile

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<LegalModel>, IEnumerable<LegalDTO>>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.LegalId , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LegalId ))
.ForMember(dest => dest.LegalName , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LegalName ))
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
{
    //Logic that Maps Person properties of LegalModel to Person and Person2 property of LegalDto
}
```

How do I map the properties

- LegalModel.LegalId  to LegalDto.LegalId
- LegalModel.LegalName  to LegalDto.LegalName
- LegalModel.PersonId and LegalModel.Name to LegalDto.Person based on some logic

and

- LegalModel.PersonId and LegalModel.Name to LegalDto.Person2 based on some logic

Edit: from [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408338/how-to-map-normally-with-2-class-but-use-aftermap-in-ienumerable-of-the-same-2-o#comment110375502_62408515):

> I want to map `LegalId` and `LegalName` normally but want to map `Person` and `Person2` on after map only if its `IEnumerable`

Comment: I suspect you will need a [custom type converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) here. That gives you full control over the mapping process.

Comment: I am aware that you can map Legal and LegalDTO withought adding the ienum on the createmap. The reason I add it is because I need it on the aftermap. Which I loop on the IEnumerable. Do you see my problem? I need it to be ienumerable<LegalModel> instead of just LegalModel so I can loop through it on the aftermap.

Answer (score 1):

Automapper supports enumerable mappings out of the box, so you don't need to set up them if you have set up mapping of classes. Given this:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<LegalModel, LegalDTO>()...);
```

This should work:

```
new List<LegalModel>  source = ...  
IEnumerable<LegalDTO> mapped = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<LegalDTO>>(source);
```

So just set up your `LegalModel` -> `LegalDTO` mapping correctly and let Automapper handle collections.

Comment: this doesnt answer my question regarding the aftermap used to map LegalDto.Person and Person2 though

Comment: I am aware that you can map Legal and LegalDTO withought adding the ienum on the createmap. The reason I add it is because I need it on the aftermap. Which I loop on the IEnumerable. Do you see my problem? I need it to be ienumerable<LegalModel> instead of just LegalModel so I can loop through it on the aftermap.

Comment: foreach(LegalModel in src){...}

Comment: @AndrewMcmellan The "Logic that Maps Person properties of LegalModel to Person and Person2 property of LegalDto" needs to happen only if you map collections?

Comment: Yes. that is my dillema. I want to map LegalId and LegalName Normally but want to map Person and Person2 on after map only if its and Ienumerable